# MySQL SELECT query gets stale data sometimes

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) to do the MySQL work in my project. But I'm not sure if this is a problem about Sequelize or MySQL itself. (I think Sequelize might only do the interaction with MySQL, and wouldn't have any influence on the results returned?)

The problem is:

I tried to **execute 3 same `SELECT` queries synchronously several times**.

**No other operations were being done at that moment**.

As the <strike>pic</strike> code shown, as an example of some wrong cases, **the 1st and 3rd queries get stale data which should be updated to be as the 2nd result**.

<strike>(pic: https://ws1.sinaimg.cn/large/006tKfTcgy1ftcq3wxrg3j30vg0v4ali.jpg)</strike>

code:

```
2018-07-17 00:49:24,142 INFO 83779 [model] SELECT `id`, `eval_id`, `user_id`, `type`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at` FROM `eval_vote` AS `eval_vote` WHERE ((`eval_vote`.`deleted_at` > '2018-07-16 16:49:24' OR `eval_vote`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) AND `eval_vote`.`id` = '68'); (30ms)
{ id: 68,
  eval_id: 5,
  user_id: 1,
  type: 2,
  created_at: 2018-07-16T15:59:44.000Z,
  updated_at: 2018-07-16T16:49:21.000Z,
  deleted_at: null }
2018-07-17 00:49:24,169 INFO 83779 [model] SELECT `id`, `eval_id`, `user_id`, `type`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at` FROM `eval_vote` AS `eval_vote` WHERE ((`eval_vote`.`deleted_at` > '2018-07-16 16:49:24' OR `eval_vote`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) AND `eval_vote`.`id` = '68'); (24ms)
{ id: 68,
  eval_id: 5,
  user_id: 1,
  type: 1,
  created_at: 2018-07-16T15:59:44.000Z,
  updated_at: 2018-07-16T16:49:23.000Z,
  deleted_at: null }
2018-07-17 00:49:24,201 INFO 83779 [model] SELECT `id`, `eval_id`, `user_id`, `type`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at` FROM `eval_vote` AS `eval_vote` WHERE ((`eval_vote`.`deleted_at` > '2018-07-16 16:49:24' OR `eval_vote`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) AND `eval_vote`.`id` = '68'); (29ms)
{ id: 68,
  eval_id: 5,
  user_id: 1,
  type: 2,
  created_at: 2018-07-16T15:59:44.000Z,
  updated_at: 2018-07-16T16:49:21.000Z,
  deleted_at: null }
```

The `UPDATE` operation to the row `{id: 68, ...}` was done seconds ago before the `SELECT`s executed. I'm sure it was executed successfully because every time I updated this row, I went to Navicat (a GUI management tool) to refresh to see if the result was right. And it was. But in my Sequelize result

How could this weird thing happens? I know that MySQL has query cache itself. But shouldn't the cache be cleared whenever a row updated or inserted?

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry but I think I've attach a pic link right below my bold text? Thanks.

Comment: We don't generally want pictures . Just paste formatted text. See what others do and try to replicate

Comment: @Strawberry All right. I've transformed my picture into code text. Thanks.